# C# prevent changes made to list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

```
List<Box[]> boxesList = new List<Box[]>(); // create a new list that contains boxes
Box[] boxes = new Box[9];                  // create an array of boxes
boxesList.Add(boxes);                      // add the boxes to the list
boxesList[0][0] = new Box(2, new Point(0, 0)); // change the content of the list
boxes[0] = new Box(1,new Point(0,0));      //  change content of the boxarray
```

The problem is after initializing the first 
element of the boxes array. The boxesList is also changed.
I think the problem is that the box
array is stored as a reference in the list.
Is there a way around this? 
So that the boxeslist will not be changed by changing the box array

Comment: So you want to store a clone of the array, rather than the original array, in the list? Is that your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is after initializing the first element of the boxes array. The boxesList is also changed.

No, it's not. The `boxesList` has *exactly* the same contents as it had before: a *reference* to the array of boxes. There's only *one* array here. If you change it, whether that's through `boxesList[0]` or `boxes`, you're changing the same array.

If you want to take a copy of the array, you need to do so explicitly. It's up to you whether you create a copy of the array and put the reference to the copy in the list, or copy the array afterwards.

See my article on [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more information, remembering that all array types are reference types.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will make a copy of the array and put that in a list

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are references. When you put the array into the list, it is just copying the *reference*. If you want a new *separate* array (of the same actual objects), then you'll need to copy the array:

```
boxedList.Add((Box[])boxes.Clone());
```

Note that this is only a shallow copy; the line:

```
boxes[0].SomeProp = newValue;
```

would still be shown in both places. If that isn't OK, then a deep-copy might be useful, but frankly I'd suggest it would be easier to make `Box` immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the index of the first element in the list. Change the code to this for both boxes to appear in the list.

```
        List<Box[]> boxesList = new List<Box[]>(); // create a new list that contains boxes
        Box[] boxes = new Box[9];                  // create an array of boxes
        boxesList.Add(new Box[] { new Box(2, new Point(0, 0))}); // change the content of the list
        boxes[0] = new Box(1, new Point(0, 0)); 
        boxesList.Add(boxes);                      // add the boxes to the list
```